# What is the smallest product, $m$, of $6$ distinct odd primes such that $\frac{d+\frac{m}{d}}{2}$ is prime for all $d$ dividing $m$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization, programming

I am currently working on a sequence, $a_n$, that is defined as follows:

$$a_n\text{ is the smallest product of }n\text{ distinct odd primes, }m=p_1p_2\dots p_n\text{, such that }\frac{d+\frac{m}{d}}{2}\text{ is prime for all }d\text{ dividing }m.$$

This sequence is currently known to five terms: $3, 21, 105, 1365, 884037$ (OEIS [A128281](https://oeis.org/A128281)). I have coded a program in an attempt to find a sixth term. During my search, I was able to determine that all members of the sequence except the first are congruent to $1{\pmod{4}}$. My best method currently is to test every number congruent to $1{\pmod{4}}$ starting at $255257 = 3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot11\cdot13\cdot17+2$. My program tests first if each number is a product of six distinct odd primes, then tests if it fits the divisor requirements for the sequence. With my program I have determined that $a_6>10^9$. Are there any optimizations I could make so that my program takes less time to search? Is there any reason to suspect that $a_6$ does not exist? If so, would this be the case for further terms as well?

Comment: An acceleration is surely to permute over the six-tuples containing distinct odd primes. But probably the user posting this OEIS sequence has done long calculations already. Maybe, you have to be very very patient.

Comment: This sequence specifically hadn't been touched since its creation in 2007, so I thought I might have a decent chance at finding the next term.

Comment: As of Aug 27 2020, it appears it was checked up to $a_6\gt 2\cdot 10^{11}$.

Comment: I can approve that $a_6>10^{10}$ and probably even larger than $10^{12}$. I could find an example such that none of the $64$ numbers has a factor less than $293$ , so I think $a_6$ exists. But since we have several relatively large numbers that have to be prime and in total $32$ (the others are equal to those), I think, $a_6$ is very large, maybe $20$ digits or more.